# Is there a Doppler effect on the surface of an expanding balloon?

Tags: waves, cosmology, doppler-effect

Imagine a stationary transmitter which vibrates the surface of the balloon and a stationary receiver half way around the balloon that can pick up these waves. Let the balloon expand. Will the frequency of the received waves change due to a Doppler effect?

As the balloon expands, the tension in the surface will increase which could alter the velocity of the waves. This is not a Doppler effect and could be allowed for.

I ask the question because the motion of both the source and the receiver due to the expansion is perpendicular to the direction the waves are travelling in, though there is also a velocity of recession, which is different to the velocity of expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the mechanical properties of the balloon were not affected by being stretched. That is, suppose you took a balloon and stretched it $10$%. The speed of waves is the same as an unstretched balloon. The frequency and wavelength would be the same in both. Travel time would increase $10$% because the distance traveled increased that much.

Now suppose you emit a wave as the balloon stretches. Let us call the stretching rate $\alpha$. In a time interval $\Delta t$, a length $l$ grows by $\Delta l$. $$\alpha = \frac{\Delta l}{l \Delta t}$$

If the source and receiver are separated by a distance d, their separation is increasing at velocity $\dot d =\alpha d$. So

$$d = d_0 e^{\alpha t}$$

The wave is emitted with period $T_0$ and travels at a constant velocity $v$. So the wavelength is initially $\lambda_0 = vT_0$.

But by the time the wave has traveled a distance $d$, the separation between successive crests has increased to $\lambda_0 e^{\alpha t}$ (assuming $\alpha$ is constant).

The wave still travels at velocity $v$, so the time it takes to advance by $\lambda$ is

$$T = \lambda/v = T_0e^{\alpha t}$$

There is a Doppler shift. This is much like the expansion of the universe. Here are a couple Veritasium videos that might be of interest.

- [What Actually Expands In An Expanding Universe?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DrBQg_n2Uo)
- [Misconceptions About the Universe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBr4GkRnY04)

Comment: Is this not more akin to cosmological redshift. It is due to the increasing size of the balloon, not velocity, and is spread across the whole balloon. Shouldn't a Doppler effect occur directly at the source?